# "No such column 'New_Field__c' on entity 'Custom_Object__c'" when querying Object deployed via Change Set

Tags: soql, custom-object, deployment, custom-field, change-set

I've deployed an Inbound Change Set at one of my Sandbox instances. With this Change Set there was a new field created on one of the objects. However, the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE New_Field__c = NULL
```

Returns an error:

> [object Object]: FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE New_Field__c !=
>   NULL ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:46 No such column 'New_Field__c'
>   on entity 'Custom_Object__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom
>   field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please
>   reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

The `Custom_Field__c` is present in `Object Manager`. I'm 100% sure both field's and object's names are typed correctly.

What may be wrong here?

Comment: Check for the field level security. Is field visible to sys admin ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost certainly omitted permissions to read this field for your profile. Edit the Field Level Security and make sure you have at least Read access.